Deployment integrity protection methods
[I'm not sure if this is the correct place for this kind of meta question. Please suggest another forum if required.]
I use python, pandas and a few other python libraries in my data science projects.
Being a developer of the core script logic, I provide the python code to be deployed. Core logic works well when the inputs are as expected and have access to the expected python environment / packages / etc.
However, the deployment is manual process in my case which is done by a different team and hence, is prone to human errors. Without having access to the server myself, I need a mechanism through which I can log out:

Some form of code signature of each python file in my project to ensure the code I provide is the code which is deployed.
Some form of signature on the python and its package versions to ensure the versions are correct as per my specifications.
Some form of signature on the input data (in the form of pandas dataframe) to be assured of the data integrity.

These signatures should be independent of the time and the CPU architecture. How do I generate these signatures / hashes?
Through this exercise, looking at the system logs, I'd get to know if the output we get is not as per expectation, is there an issue with deployment and inputs (where I can hold dev ops team accountable) or if there is an issue with the logic itself (where I can hold myself accountable).
